# Stretch footer background till bottom: 0;

Tags: css

I have the following problem. The footer of my website is placed correctly right under the content. However I want the background of the footer (white) to extend all the way to the bottom of the window. Please look at this template: [link removed] . I know how to stick the footer to the bottom, but I want it to stay where it is and have the blue background gap removed instead.

Is there any possibility?

I'm also open to javascript solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by doing:

```
.Footer {
    margin-bottom: -182px;
}

body {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change you `CSS`
In your `.Footer` class remove the `position: relative;`

Comment: Thanks, but I already had this solution. The problem is, I need the blue space beneath filled up. Because when relative is removed, there is too much space between the content and the footer. I need the footer to come very close to the content, and stretch the white background all the way to the bottom of the window.

Comment: @GillianLo-Wong: Seem like you using **position: relative** every where..any reason?? Otherwise remove it and try

Comment: Because the footer is a big image (400px height) and I need it to overlap the content until the white bar is against the content.. I dont want the big white space between content and footer. I just want the blue space below the footer to turn white.

Comment: using something **margin-bottom: -182px;** may cause other problem. Anyway, it will be better to test against all the browsers :)